# content.getSelection() is not working when selected text is in iframe?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon

In Firefox Extension development, I wants to get selected content from the chrome page, when I use content.getSelection(), its working fine .

But if the selected text is in the iframe, its not working. anyone can help me ?

Comment: Can you show me some code? JSFiddle would be nice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to call `getSelection()` on the `window` object where text has been selected. For example, if there is an `<iframe id="iframe">` in the content document, you would use the following to get the selection in that frame:

```js
alert(content.document.getElementById("iframe").contentWindow.getSelection());
```

If you don't know where the user selected text and you want to look at all frames then you should go through them recursively starting at the top level, something like this:

```js
function getSelection(wnd)
{
  var result = wnd.getSelection();

  for (var i = 0; !result && i < wnd.frames.length; i++)
    result = getSelection(wnd.frames[i]);

  return result;
}

alert(getSelection(content));
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, and i have one more question, I am developing firefox extension using the below web page https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Building_an_Extension, whether i have to try Add-on SDK or both are same..

Comment: @Benz: No, classic XUL-based extensions and Add-on SDK are very different. The Add-on SDK has lower barriers to entry but sometimes it's too limiting. Which approach you should choose depends largely on what you plan to do and personal preferences.

Comment: I think you maybe could test the rangeCount property in your result object (object Selection) when you use it as a condition in your loop.