# Get selected text with JS - even in iFrames

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, textselection

Right now i get the selected text with `window.getSelection().toString()`. But unfortunately this doesn't work for text in iFrames. It's for a chrome extension, so i don't need to hear about how iFrames suck ;).

Comment: Does the way it is handled for a firefox extension work? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10990690/content-getselection-is-not-working-when-selected-text-is-in-iframe

Answer (score 0):

If you have a reference to the iframe in question then

```
iframeEl.contentWindow.getSelection().toString();
```

... will do the job. If you want to get the selected text from all iframes, you could use `window.frames`, which is a collection of `Window` objects rather than frame/iframe elements:

```
var selectedTexts = [];
Array.prototype.forEach.call(window.frames, function(frameWin) {
    selectedTexts.push( frameWin.getSelection().toString() );
});
```